# htaccess - Rewrite Rule SSL Redirect to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I want a rewrite rule that redirects everything to https:// and www.

For example https://example.com should be going to https://www.example.com

This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?DOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.DOMAIN\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I followed the site so I just used it as is. But it worked for my website https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
 # The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
 # or .htaccess context
```

I went through it and it worked for me. Here's where I got mine from https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Comment: That works the same as mine currently does. I want https://lalna.com to go to https://www.lalna.com with the "www."

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.DOMAIN.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

This will redirect SSL non-www ( https://domain.com ) to ( https://www.domain.com )

If you want to redirect non-ssl and non-www ( http://domain.com ) to ( https://www.domain.com ) , then try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.DOMAIN.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Sorry not working. I've changed DOMAIN to my domain and it is doing the same as what I had.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and try one more time.

Comment: Are you using your own server with tomcat of do you use a hosting? I use Hostgator and with familiarity with tomcat its been a smooth process. But its worked for me with the www. Cause I had used it as a 301 redirect to help promote my new subdomains

Comment: Thats because your browser has cached all of your previous 301 redirects, try clearing these caches or visit your site by a diffrent web browser,

Comment: I've cleared my cache and I can confirm it is still letting me access the https version without the www. the same as my original was doing.